# Testing for HTTP headers being returned from an ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I've added and removed a number of headers for security reasons, using two classic strategies in an MVC Application:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```

And via the Web.Config:

```
<customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
</customHeaders>
```

Right now I am using **NUnit** paired with **RhinoMocks** for testing, FWIW.

Given the difficulties with mocking `HttpContext`, **what would be a good way to ensure that custom headers are either present or not present in the http response for any of the views I return?**

Comment: Can you show one of the tests you've tried so far so your problem can be replicated and them maybe someone can provide a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to verify this behaviour is through an Component test. The reason is quite simple; You are trying to ensure a security issue, in UT nothing will ensure that your component will use this behaviour. I can offer you several options(code weaving tools, add public method and etc..) to test it as a UT however, IMO this is a classic case for Integration test.

To Component test this behaviour do the following steps:

Raise a self host server([Self-Host ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) or [OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api))

Then in call a method and assert that the answer doesn't contains the headers:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();  

Assert.IsFalse(myHttpWebResponse.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Frame-Options");
Assert.IsFalse(myHttpWebResponse.Headers.ContainsKey("Server");
Assert.IsFalse(myHttpWebResponse.Headers.ContainsKey("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
//todo: add logic which read the following parameters from the configuration
Assert.IsFalse(myHttpWebResponse.Headers.ContainsKey("X-AspNet-Version");
Assert.AreEquals("DENY", myHttpWebResponse.Headers["X-Frame-Options"]);
```

Comment: As an addendum to this question and Fox's answer. Its possible to build your own abstractions for the Microsoft sealed classes, and then mock and test, or you can download one of several abstraction projects, including one from Microsoft.  Also refer to this question for more good information, particularly on why we have these issues with HttpContext: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947471/unable-to-examine-reponse-headers-in-unit-test